# Create custom open graph stories on facebook having multiple objects, in ios app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-ios-sdk

I am able to create a story having heading as follows:

User **ran** 0.2 miles with Strava.

Now I want to insert multiple objects in single sentence as follows:

User **ran** 0.2 miles on **Monday** with Strava.

I am able to create multiple actions and objects, but problem is to use them in one sentence.

How to solve this?